# Write user.config file file to user folder when run under task scheduler

Tags: c#, windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a C# console app which updates a user setting upon completion:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.StatusDate = DateTime.Now;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

I have Windows Task Scheduler configured to run my app as a particular user, without logon required, with highest privileges. The app runs fine, but the user.config file which results is written under C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\MyApp\user.config

If I use the "runas" command from the command prompt to run as the same user which Task Scheduler uses, the user.config file gets written under that user's folder as I would expect.

In case it makes any difference, this is an Azure Windows Server 2012 R2 VM.

How can I make my app write the config settings to the specified user's folder and not the Default user folder when run under Task Scheduler?

Comment: does making your application run as administrator always help you solve your problem

Comment: The problem is the default user wont have access to your users home folder..

Comment: @AliEzzatOdeh Good thought, but sadly changing the properties of the exe to run as administrator for all users does not solve the problem

Comment: @BugFinder the problem is actually the reverse... the app is run as a particular user, but the settings are being written under the Default user

Comment: is the scope of the app settings user or application?

Comment: @BugFinder the scope is user